# Koa-swagger: access-control-origin error after cors being set

Tags: cors, swagger, koa

I am playing around with koa and swagger. It gives me the error of "may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings" even after I set the cors.

App.js

```
var cors = require('koa-cors');

var swaggerApp = koa(),
    port = 8080;

var options = {
    origin: '*',
    headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization','Origin', 'X-Requested-With']
}


curl i http://localhost:8080/api-docs.json

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization,Origin,X-Requested-With
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 203
Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2015 17:13:55 GMT
Connection: keep-alive


{"basePath":"http://localhost:8080","apiVersion":"1.0","swaggerVersion":"1.0","swaggerURL":"/swagger","swaggerJSON":"/api-docs.json","apis":[{"path":"/api-docs.json/root","description":"All about API"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the swagger ui cannot give complete warnings when there's a CORS error.  In your case, please look to see that http://localhost:8080/api-docs.json/root exists.  If not, you might get the same error message.

It also looks like the swagger definition is quite old (1.0).  Can you look at using a newer library, such as https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node?